# How to transfer this list to a 3xN matrix? Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, python-itertools

```
my_list = ["TITLE","COMPANY","TENURE",
"Board Member","Softbank Corp","06/2007–06/2015",
 "Chairman","Alibaba.Com Ltd","10/2007–PRESENT",
"Board Member","Huayi Brothers","FORMER"]
```

I have the above list and I want to transfer it to a 3xN format (3 columns, N rows)

Expected outputs:

```
TITLE           COMPANY        TENURE
Board Member  Softbank Corp  06/2007–06/2015
Chairman     Alibaba.Com Ltd 10/2007–PRESENT
Board Member  Huayi Brothers  FORMER
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using pandas?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use pandas dataframe:

The DataFrame can be created using a single list or a list of lists.

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = ["TITLE","COMPANY","TENURE",
"Board Member","Softbank Corp","06/2007–06/2015",
 "Chairman","Alibaba.Com Ltd","10/2007–PRESENT",
"Board Member","Huayi Brothers","FORMER"]

# Convert flat list into nested list with 3 items
data_ = [my_list[i:i + 3] for i in range(0,len(my_list),3)] 

#Create a DataFrame from Lists 
print (pd.DataFrame(data_[1:],columns=data_[0:1][0]))
```

output:

```
          TITLE          COMPANY           TENURE
0  Board Member    Softbank Corp  06/2007–06/2015
1      Chairman  Alibaba.Com Ltd  10/2007–PRESENT
2  Board Member   Huayi Brothers           FORMER
```